# addition operator with pass by reference

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload the addition operator,with the following prototype:

```
obj operator+(obj&, obj&);
```

this works for `a+b` but triggers an error on `a+b+c`

g++ spits out the following error:

```
test.cpp:17:6: error: no match for ‘operator+’ in ‘operator+((* & a), (* & b)) + c’
test.cpp:17:6: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:10:5: note: obj operator+(obj&, obj&)
error: no match for 'operator+' in 'operator+(obj&, obj&) 
note: candidates are: obj operator+(obj&, onj&)
```

Comment: Don't use a non-const reference unless you're changing it. Changing the caller's variable in `operator+` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your argument is a non-const reference and the operator returns a new object.

Thus, `a+b` evaluates to a temporary object, which cannot bind to a non-`const` reference as per the standard. Thus it cannot be passed as an argument to your `operator+`. The solution is most likely to use a `const` reference as @chris suggests, because you should not be modifying the operands of `operator+`.

No-one would expect that and thus I personally think it would be bad style to do so.

Comment: Ok. I do need to modify a value. Nothing that the user of the class needs to know about though. I got around thatWith the mutable keyword

Answer (score 0):

You can assume that the left hand side of an equation is always referring to "this" object which means you can change the signature of the overloaded operator to:

```
obj operator+(const obj &other){
    // Add value of "this" to value of other
    // Return obj
}
```